# how to download mnist dataset 1.0.0 through tfds.builder?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

I'm trying to use tfds.builder to download mnist dataset,
due to the need for my task, the working environment asking the dataset version to be 1.0.0, and it can access to internet.
I tried to use

```
builder = tfds.builder(name = 'mnist:1.0.0',data_dir='tensorflow_datasets2')
builder.download_and_prepare()
```

but it returns :

```
AssertionError: Failed to construct dataset mnist:1.0.0: Dataset mnist cannot be loaded at version 1.0.0, only: 3.0.1.
```

does anyone know how to download the version 1.0.0 through tfds.builder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade the tensorflow_dataset, ex:

```
pip install tensorflow-datasets==1.2
```

then it is able to download older versions of the datasets.